# Basic array issue in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Looking for help with a basic array problem. Program has to read a sentence and store the frequencies of the word lengths in an array and then print out how many words are 1 letter words, 2 letter words etc.

I'm a pretty raw java programmer but have made a stab at it below would greatly appreciate some guidance. What I have seems to compile but spits out some garbled hex when I run the program and enter a sentence.

When I enter a sentence into the program I get an **output** like this:

```
[I@eb42cbf
[I@eb42cbf
[I@eb42cbf
[I@eb42cbf
[I@eb42cbf
[I@eb42cbf
```

**My code:**

```
class WordCount
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int wordList[] = new int[20];
        System.out.println("Please enter a sentence.");

        for (int i = 0; i <= wordList.length; i++)
        {
            String s = Console.readToken();
            int x = s.length();
            wordList[x]++;
        }

        int x = 1;

        while (x < wordList.length)
        {
            if (wordList[x] > 0)
                System.out.println(x + "-letter words: " + wordList[x]);
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Smells like homework... Moreover, where does `count` come from? You did not define it. Maybe that should be `wordList`.

Comment: Afraid not, studying for an exam coming up next month using excercises from a book, no solutions or hints are provided unfortunately. I know im doing something silly wrong just cant spot it.

Comment: See my first comment. Additionally, the `i` in the second loop starts from `1`. I think it should start from `0`.

Comment: @Baz we can probably assume there is no 0-letter word ;-)

Comment: @assylias You got me there :) But he should use a `for` loop rather than a `while` loop.

Comment: @user1564741 Your code as it is does not compile. Please post the code you are actually using.

Comment: @Baz yes sorry I should have explained I started at 1 in line with number of letters in words.

Comment: @user1564741 But what about the other comments? What is the output you get?

Comment: @assylias Edited the above code to reflect my compiling code. Cheers

Comment: @Dave What is Console.readToken()? There isn't such a method in the standard [Console class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html).

Comment: It reads in the next word. Recommended by a previous lecturer who was a big advocate of the console class.

Comment: I'm saying that the method readToken does not exist in the console class...

Comment: @Dave The output looks like you are trying to output the WHOLE array at once. Are you sure, that the code you supplied above is exactly the same as the one you use?

Comment: Its a different Console class, the lecturer developed it and insisted we all used it and taught his lectures with it. Bit of an ego-maniac but thats for another day. I updated the original post to include the output I am getting.

Comment: @Dave it makes no sense to force you to use his custom library when the JDK contains a class that does exactly the same thing. Anyway, your code works fine with a Scanner, so if what you posted is exactly what you run, the only possibility is that Console.readToken() does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Don't forget to accept one of the answers if you get it to work...

Comment: Maybe so, best I get out of the habit of using that anyway. I see with your solution that it requires 19 lines of input before it prints out. Is there a way to input a one line sentence and then receive the output summary? If it requires a lot more code then it may be beyond my abilities at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are my suggestions:

- use a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) instead of your Console.readToken, which is not part of the standard JDK
- use standard variable names (i for a counter is better than x)
- the rest of your code works fine
- but I would use a for loop instead of the while because you know how many times you need to loop

Here is my version - The changes are: use of a scanner, renaming x into i and changing the while loop into a for loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int wordList[] = new int[20];
    System.out.println("Please enter a sentence.");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //Use a scanner, part of the standard JDK

    for (int i = 0; i <= wordList.length; i++) {
        String s = scanner.next(); //reads the next string
        int length = s.length();
        wordList[length]++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) { //use a for loop
        if (wordList[i] > 0) {
            System.out.println(i + "-letter words: " + wordList[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should the while loop not be

```
while(i < wordlist.Length){
  if (wordlist[i] > 0){
      System.out.println(i + "-letter words: " + wordlist[i]);
  }
  i++;      
}
```

Comment: That does not make sense: your proposal will be an infinite loop if there is a bucket with no words.

Comment: Corrected the i++, was trying to illustrate that the OP was using 'count[i]' instead of 'wordlist[i]'.

Comment: Apologies I changed the name of my array in an early version hence the discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static long wordcount(String line){
    long numWords = 0;
    int index = 0;
    boolean prevWhiteSpace = true;
    while(index < line.length()){
        char c = line.charAt(index++);
        boolean currWhiteSpace = Character.isWhitespace(c);
        if(prevWhiteSpace && !currWhiteSpace){
            numWords++;
        }
        prevWhiteSpace = currWhiteSpace;
    }
    return numWords;
}
```

Comment: I think what the OP needs is an explanation of what he is doing wrong rather than a solution...

Comment: Appreciate the solution but would benefit more from advice on where Im going wrong with my own answer. Thanks people.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that when a sentence is entered like: "This is a sentence that", the output should be:

4-letter words: 2

2-letter words: 1

1-letter words: 1

8-letter words: 1

My Code:

```
  import java.util.HashMap;
  import java.util.Scanner;

        class WordCount {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                HashMap<Integer, Integer> statistic = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

                System.out.println("Please enter a sentence.");
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                String s = in.nextLine();

                String[] words = s.split(" ");

                for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    if (statistic.containsKey(words[i].length())) {
                        Integer value = statistic.get(words[i].length());
                        statistic.put(words[i].length(), value + 1);
                    } else
                        statistic.put(words[i].length(), 1);
                }

                for (Integer num : statistic.keySet()) {

                    Integer key = num;
                    Integer value = statistic.get(num);
                    System.out.println(key + "-letter words: " + value);

                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach :

```
int wordList[] = new int[20];
    System.out.println("Please enter a sentence.");
    String s = "";
    try{
        BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        s  = bufferRead.readLine();        
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String[] s1 = s.split(" ");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < s1.length ; i++){
        int len = s1[i].length(); 
        wordList[len]++; 
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) { //use a for loop
    if (wordList[i] > 0) {
        System.out.println(i + "-letter words: " + wordList[i]);
       }
    }
```